# D flip flop with asynchronous level triggered reset

Tags: verilog, flipflop

Ref : [Is making a D flip flop with asynchronous level triggered reset possible?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28369/is-making-a-d-flip-flop-with-asynchronous-level-triggered-reset-possible)

My code :

```
always @ ( posedge clock, posedge rst)
begin
if(rst) q = 1'b0 ;
else q = d ;
end
```

Waveform :

[image]

Error :

Between 100 and 150 ns, the output followed the d input although there was no clock edge. In other words, it behaved like a latch.

I wanted to make a positive edge triggered d flip flop with asynchronous positive level triggered reset, which I succeeded after examining the reference link above.

Prior to this, I was using the code given above. As you can see, the only difference is that I have used blocking assignment while the reference uses non blocking assignment.

Now I know that non blocking assignment schedules the values in contrast to blocking assignment. However I am not able to understand how is this affecting my design ?
In other words, can someone explain step by step or in little detail why changing non blocking to blocking is resulting in incorrect design.

Additionally, I also tried this code :

```
always @ ( posedge clock, rst)
begin
if(rst) q = 1'b0 ;
else q = d ;
end
```

which also resulted in erroneous design. But why, I wasnt able to understand.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the test-bench and tell us what simulator and version you are using. If your design is only one flip-flop, blocking vs non-blocking assignment shouldn't be an issue. My guess is there is a glitch on clock or rst, or bizarre simulator behavior.

Comment: @Greg . You were right. I use modelsim student version. Today I reinstalled the simulator after your comment. Seems like it now works as expected. Just one last thing, can you explain the last block of code ; it sure doesnt result in FF but why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer for blocking vs non-blocking flip-flops assignment is already answered on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4657591/1959732). That answer also references to a paper by Cliff Cummings, [here](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf).

Now, the code for your second attempt will always result in with the behavior shown in the waveform, even with non-blocking assignments:

```
always @(posedge clock, rst)
begin
  if (rst) q <= 1'b0 ;
  else     q <= d ;
end
```

This is because the sensitivity list for signal `rst` is incorrect. The `posedge` keyword only applies to the signal immediately right of the keyword and not the following signals after the comma. `@(posedge clock, rst)` is equivalent to `@(posedge clock, posedge rst, negedge rst)`. The `else` condition will be evaluated on the falling edged of `rst`, which is not desired.

A good linting, synthesizer, or LEC (logical equivalently check) tool should flag the dual edge trigger on `rst` as an issue; possible as a warning.

Comment: `@` is trigger by events: edge triggered, value change, or triggered `event` type (not synthesizable) within the sensitivity list. `posedge rst` with `if (rst)` tells the synthesizer to use a D-flip-flip with an active high asynchronous reset. Asynchronous is for events outside of the synchronous domain. For a active low reset async reset you need `negedge rst` with `if (!rst)`. For sync reset, remove `rst` from the sensitivity list. Behavior will be correct in simulation. You may run into trouble on FPGAs with limited number of flops with async set/rst, but that should get errors/warnings